# FME: How to retain Field names in reader?

Tags: fme-form, schema-architecture

I am having problems with field names in my writer using fme 2014. When I "generate" a workspace and pre-define the reader and writer before I add transformers, the readers field names are automatically retained by the Writer. However, when I create a blank workspace and add the reader and writer separately, the field names are not migrated to the writer unless I use "dynamic schemas" - But in this case, the fields are not visibile in the dropdown list under the Writer, and under properties I can´t delete the attribute fields that I don´t want. Even if I deactivate them in the reader, they are still retained by the writer!

How can I get more control over which attribute fields get written to the writer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the field names across when your using dynamic schemas by selecting the writer right click and copy attributes from Feature Type...

Then you can go to properties and delete the fields you do not require.

[image]